# Compare fields in two Object and update one to the other in Java

Tags: java

I have running into an issue to update existing data with whatever the changed made by user.

For example, I have one Company Object as below

```
public class Company {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String url;

    //Getter and setter.....
}
```

Now I have one company instance with data as below

```
Company company = new Company();
company.setId("id12345678");
company.setName("company Old Name");
company.setUrl("company Old Url");
```

Now user has create another company instance just to update the `name` and `url` of existing `Company`

```
Company newCompany = new Company();
newCompany.setId("id12345678");
newCompany.setName("company New Name");
newCompany.setUrl("company New Url");
```

As can see, the new instance of `Company` has the same `Id` as the old one but with different `name` and `url`.

Is there any Utility tools/library can simple find all the differences between those two object and apply the changes to the `company` instance? (don't really want to write code to manually compare each field)

Something like

```
company = AwesomeLibraryUtils.compareAndApplyDifferences(company, newCompany);
```

After this, the `company` instance remain the same id but with all the new values of `name` and `url` from `newCompany` instance.

Thanks.

Comment: dont know but see if this meets your requirement https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff

Comment: I'll just leave this here: [*"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks virendrao, I have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no really utility that can "find and apply" the differences (as far as I know), however, there is reflection (as other said), like Apache Comparator (which is a powerfull class).

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ComparatorUtils.html

As for "applying differences", there is also a tool in Apache (BeanUtils this time): http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/ which is "`copyProperties(Object o1, Object o2)`" wihchi will copy all properties (fields) from one object to another.

So, you just have to compare the objects and if their are differences, copy one into the other.

Except for performance problems, I don't see why you would copy only the fields that are differents (because if you copy the fields that are the same, well there won't be any difference). If you have to copy only the field that are different, I guess you'll have to make your own tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically I can achieve this by using the two utils from apache commons.

Answer (score 2):

Use reflect to find all the of results of getters and setters in company and newCompany.

Basically, what I am doing here are as the following:

1. Put all the results of getters in newCompany into a HashMap called hm.

2. Scan through the results of getters in company. If hm doesn't contain any one of the results of getters in company, then the two companies are considered different.

3. If the two companies are different, set the values in company as the values in newCompany.

```
public static void compareAndApplyDifferences(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if(!o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass())) {
        return;
    }
    // check if the result of getters in o1 and o2 are different
    boolean isDiff = false;
    Class<? extends Object> c1 = o1.getClass();
    Class<? extends Object> c2 = o2.getClass();
    Method[] methods1 = c1.getMethods();
    Method[] methods2 = c2.getMethods();
    Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Method method2 : methods2) {
        if (isGetter(method2)) {
            try {
                Object getterResult = method2.invoke(o2);
                hm.put(method2.getName().substring(3), getterResult);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    for (Method method1 : methods1) {
        if (isGetter(method1)) {
            try {
                String getterResult = (String) method1.invoke(o1);
                if (!hm.containsValue(getterResult)) {
                    isDiff = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    if (isDiff) {
        // set the values in o1 as the values in o2
        for (Method method1 : methods1) {
            if (isSetter(method1)) {
                try {
                    method1.invoke(o1, hm.get(method1.getName().substring(3)));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

private static boolean isGetter(Method method) {
    if (!method.getName().startsWith("get"))
        return false;
    if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 0)
        return false;
    if (void.class.equals(method.getReturnType()))
        return false;
    return true;
}

private static boolean isSetter(Method method) {
    if (!method.getName().startsWith("set"))
        return false;
    if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Here's the demonstration of my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Company company = new Company();
    company.setId("id12345678");
    company.setName("company Old Name");
    company.setUrl("company Old Url");

    Company newCompany = new Company();
    newCompany.setId("id12345678");
    newCompany.setName("company New Name");
    newCompany.setUrl("company New Url");

    AwesomeLibraryUtils.compareAndApplyDifferences(company, newCompany);

    System.out.println(company.getId());   // id12345678
    System.out.println(company.getName()); // company New Name
    System.out.println(company.getUrl());  // company New Url
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is good to have this implement, I will dig into this. For a 'quick win" with existing libraries from 3rd parties, I chose the other one as the answer. Sorry about this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should override `equals()` method. After that you will be able to check the condition `company.equals(newCompany)`

Famous IDEs support auto-generation of equals method. For example, IDEA generates it as:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Company company = (Company) o;

    if (id != null ? !id.equals(company.id) : company.id != null) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(company.name) : company.name != null) return false;
    return !(url != null ? !url.equals(company.url) : company.url != null);

}
```

Comment: Please read my question: Is there any Utility tools/library can simple find all the differences between those two object and apply the changes to the company instance?